# Trigger (Note Object) to update field on Opportunity

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to create a trigger to update a field on Opportunity. The idea is: when a Note is created on Opportunity, a field on the master object is updated to today's date.

Here's what I have so far:

```
trigger UpdateOppLastNote on Note (after insert) {

    List<Opportunity> oppLstToUpdate=new List<Opportunity>();
    for(Note nt : Trigger.new){
        if(String.valueOf(nt.parentId).startsWith('006')){
            Opportunity opp=new Opportunity(Id=nt.parentId,followup__c=Date.TODAY());
            oppLstToUpdate.add(opp);

        }
    }
}
```

It saves with no errors, but it does not fire!

Answer (score 5):

Notice how you never actually update your `List`.

```
List<Opportunity> oppLstToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();
// it's even in the name  ^^^^^^

// populate your list

update oppLstToUpdate;
```

Also note that you can more directly filter on the type of parent record:

```
if (nt.ParentId != null && nt.ParentId.getSObjectType() == Opportunity.sObjectType)
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^ if someone tries to save a record with this field empty
//              you don't want your trigger throwing an ugly
//              unhandled NullPointerException
```

Comment: Hello Adrian! Thanks for your response. 
Anyhow, it still did not work. I added the update part and the filter, but it did not fire.

Comment: Did you make sure the trigger is active?

Comment: Yeah! I wish my problem were that simple LOL

Comment: @SamuelLeite Are you actually inserting a `Note` record?